# Question marks where should be an X

Tags: zend-framework, unicode, character-encoding, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Zend Framework and Twitter Bootstrap for a website. From twitter bootstrap I'm using things like the alert:

```
<div class="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
  <strong>Warning!</strong> Best check yo self, you're not looking too good.
</div>
```

Where an X is supposed to appear, appears a question mark (?). I have my charset as UTF-8.

That is not the only thing that is happening but in many places where I'm supposed to have Spanish characters what appears is a question mark. Does anybody know what's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue with the SO blog and I raised it on meta. The solution may help you too. See this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141362/whats-wrong-with-the-character-encoding-in-the-blog

Comment: Definitely an encoding problem. Not only the charset but also the content has to be unicode. Which text editor are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Hex editor told me that it is × and not x . 
Remove charset from your meta in html and try again. Also, try to replace that with a 'real' x.

Comment: I guess Zend Studio didnt put it as a real X. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Dito, you might just put an simple x there instead of the multiply sign. You can also check out if it works with this HTML entity:

```
&times;
```

I've learned that encoding is a very difficult topic. There is the doctype declaration in your document – but there is also the web server (apache?) declaration and even a PHP setting. You can check out your website settings by hitting cmd+I (ctrl+i on a pc/linux) in FireFox.